# Set ID Attribute in SOAP-Body-Tag in a generated JAX-WS Client

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb, jax-ws

I have generated classes from a WSDL-file to use a webservice.
Now I need to add a specific 'Id'-Attribute to the <S:Body>-Tag.
With an example XML-Output of

```
<S:Body>
    <Object>...</Object>
</S:Body>
```

I can easily modify the specified attributes or child elements of "Object".
But I have no idea how to add an attribute to the Body-Part.

With casting my port to WSBindingProvider, I am able to add Headers (predefined or custom ones). Is there any chance to do something like that to modify the attributes of the Body as well?

**EDIT:**
To clarify my question:
The output I aim for should look like this:

```
<S:Body Id="123">
    <Object>...</Object>
</S:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can help you with your question. It is as simple as writing body.setAttribute("Id","123");

Now, the body, you can get multiple ways. If you have a SOAPMessage myMsg you can do it like this :

```
SOAPPart part = myMsg.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope envelope = part.getEnvelope();
SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
body.setAttribute("Id","123");
```

If you have a SaajSoapMessage you can get the body and set the attribute like this:

```
SaajSoapMessage message = (SaajSoapMessage) messageRequest;
SOAPMessage mes = message.getSaajMessage();
SOAPBody body = mes.getSOAPBody();
body.setAttribute("Id","123");
```